# How to store 4 digit HOUR format in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am using PHP-MySQL. I must store data for HOUR & MINUTES format, but it has more than 3 digits (e.g. 1100:10, means "one thousand and one hundred hours : ten minutes")

I found that TIME column format in MySQL only can stored maximum 3 digits for hour (xxx:xx) but cannot stored for 4 digits or more. Any suggestion to solved this?

Comment: Use `varchar` column.

Comment: use varchar instead, and input manually using php date/time function

Comment: You could convert it to minutes instead and store it as an int.

Comment: If you are going to store directly as a varchar. you can't  do time conversion after that.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least 2 options:
1. Use VARCHAR column data type to store the strings as they are, eg "1100:10".
2. Create 2 columns of data type (SMALL)INT, first for HOURS, second for MINUTES. You can then split the original time string by the colon ":" character (either in PHP, or in MySQL) and store it as 2 related values in database. Later you can concatenate the two values (INTs) back to original string.

Comment: You do not need 2 separate columns, just store everything as minutes

Comment: That is another option, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Above are nice solutions all, I didn't thought it before :)

So I use varchar/int in MySQL column then store it as a minutes, finally it is solved.